# Command to prompt for confirmation before executing another command in Shell script

Tags: shell

I am using below command to open, replace, view the change and save a file:

```
sed 's/old string/new string/g' filename > filename1; diff filename1 filename; mv filename1 filename
```

Is it possible to ask for a confirmation before executing `mv` command, something like below?

```
sed 's/old string/new string/g' filename > filename1
diff filename1 filename

<Some-Command here for user to provide Yes or NO confirmation>

mv filename1 filename
```

The intent is to validate the change and only then save it.

Answer (score 6):

I use this simple one liner on bash:

`echo -n 'Confirm: ' && read 'x' && [ $x == 'y' ] && <command>`.

This way I do not depend on another utility and it will run only when input is single `y`.

Comment: You can make it shorter: `read -p "confirm: " x; [ "$x" = "y" ] && <command>` :)

Comment: If you're using fish, write `[ "$(read -P 'confirm: ')" = 'y' ]; and <command>`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can read user input into a variable via `read`, and then compare with some acceptable value, like `"yes"`. Also you can store the command in the variable and print it to user and execute it later.

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND='mv filename1 filename'

echo "Perform the following command:"
echo
echo "    \$ $COMMAND"
echo
echo -n "Answer 'yes' or 'no': "

read REPLY
if [[ $REPLY == "yes" ]]; then
    $COMMAND
else
    echo Aborted
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: it didn't work out...i will paste the issue as answer as here formatting is so bad

Answer (score 0):

My Script is ,

```
#!/bin/bash


sed 's/This/It/g' test.xml > "test.xml1"

diff test.xml test.xml1

COMMAND ='mv test.xml1 test.xml'

echo "Perform the following command:"
echo
echo "   \$ $COMMAND"
echo
echo -n "Answer 'yes' or 'no':"

read REPLY 

if[[$REPLY=="yes"]]; then
$COMMAND

else 

echo Aborted

exit 0

fi
```

The error on executing is,

```
2c2
< This is a Test file
---
> It is a Test file
./test.sh[9]: COMMAND:  not found
Perform the following command:

   $

-n Answer 'yes' or 'no':
yes
./test.sh[19]: syntax error at line 20 : `then' unexpected
```

`mv` command didn't work.

Comment: Some space characters are important to have, and you are missing many. For example `[[` and `]]` require spaces around.

Comment: One last thing what's the command to search for a word and display the whole line (where the word present)....Thanks....

Comment: It's `grep`. `grep word some/file`

Comment: Unless it's related, better to ask a new question.